# If you archive a github pages repo will the content at github.io persist?

Tags: github, github-pages, github-archive

I have a project that I was to archive, which is https://github.com/scriptish/scriptish.github.com

This repo uses [Github Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages) to generate static content at http://scriptish.github.io/ which I don't want to disappear.

So my question if I [archive the Github repo](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/archiving-a-github-repository) then will the content at http://scriptish.github.io/ remain or vanish?

Answer (score 5):

When a Github repository is archived, the Github Pages will remain. I tried this experimentally, and the Settings for Github Pages says:

> This repository has been archived. The associated GitHub Pages site remains published but settings are read-only.

[image: Screenshot of Settings for Github Pages]